# Doesn't work validation on form passed to directive AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm building a web application using AngularJS, and I have a doubt because I don't know what is the best approach to implement a directive that use input forms. I have the following directive:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('personal', [function () {
    return {        
        restrict: 'E',
        scope : {
            model : '=ngModel',
            label : '@',
        },
        require: '^form',
        templateUrl : 'personal.html',
        link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModelController) {}
    };
}]);
```

personal.html

```
<input type="text" name="name{{label}}" ng-model="model.name" ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z]*$/">
<div class="error-container" ng-show="data.name{{label}}.$invalid">
    <small class="error" ng-show="data.name{{label}}.$error.pattern">Invalid format</small>
</div>
```

index.html

```
....
<form novalidate name="data">
   <personal label="personal" ng-model="general"></personal>
  <!-- here I will need add more tags 'personal' ..is a requirement -->
</form>
...
```

The form is presented well. But .. when the input name{{label}} have a invalid content, **the error message is not showed** (if I put the templateUrl content on index.html, that works).

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your `data.whatever` in your templateUrl does not have access to the form controller.   You have created an isolate scope thus it has no access to the form name=data.   I'm not at my computer now, so I can't give you solid examples, but read up on form controllers.

Comment: Hi Mark. Thanks for your answer, I isolate the scope because I need to create many 'personal' tags and every one must to have a different name on input, for that I concat name with {{label}} (name="name{{label}}"). There are another form to do that? Thanks for advance.